# What happens when two users try to summon same being at the same time?

Tags: naruto

Summoning Jutsu is used by user to summon any being from other place(world/dimension) to the users location.
What happens when two users try to summon same being at the same time?

I'm not telling about Katsuyu which was summoned both by Sakura & Tsunade in the Fourth Great War as it divides into many small katsuyus & this one doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it never happens we can't tell. We know that the summoned creature has to accept being summoned, and the stronger they are compared to the summoner, the more they can deny the summoning. Two examples are Naruto trying to summon the Frog Boss but getting his son instead because the Boss was busy, and the same for Sauske summoning the wrong snake.

So likely the stronger ninja would win and the summoned animal would choose if they can. Since summoning pacts are rare, it doesn't come up often.